AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'estimator'
I'm trying use the following function:
def tfexamples_input_fn(examples, feature_spec, label, mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,
                       num_epochs=None, 
                       batch_size=64):
    def ex_generator():
        for i in range(len(examples)):
            yield examples[i].SerializeToString()
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
      ex_generator, tf.dtypes.string, tf.TensorShape([]))
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=2 * batch_size + 1)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda tf_example: parse_tf_example(tf_example, label, feature_spec))
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    return dataset

I'm getting the following error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'estimator'
I have the following package versions:
tensorboard==2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow==2.16.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.15.0
tensorflow-intel==2.16.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0

Has anyone faced this issue before with estimator? I tried to recreate a whole new environment as well and reinstall everything but I got the same error above.

The problem is that tensorflow 2.16 is not supported by tensor-estimator anymore. I had to downgrade tensorflow to 2.15 for it to work.
pip install tensorflow==2.15

